# Putting two vertices within an oval on Feynmp

Tags: feynmp-auto

I am trying to draw the following diagram,

[image: Imgur]

Here is my MWE so far:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{feynmp}
\usepackage{rotating}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{fmffile}{graphwiththeelectron}
    \begin{fmfgraph*}(140,140)
      \fmfleftn{i}{9}
      \fmfrightn{o}{9}
      \fmfcmd{input vbloboval;}
      \rotatebox{90}{\fmfblobOval{0.16w}{v1}}
      \fmfblob{0.14w}{v2}
      \fmf{fermion,label=$p$}{i3,v1}
      \fmf{phantom}{v2,o5}
      \fmf{plain}{v1,v2}
      \fmf{photon}{v1,i4}
      \fmf{photon}{v1,i5}
      \fmf{photon}{v1,i6}
      \fmf{fermion,label=$p'$}{v1,i7}
  \end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
```

(I have used this [How to draw oval with FeynMP?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85052/how-to-draw-oval-with-feynmp) to draw an oval) and this is what I get out

[image: Imgur]

Unfortunately when I try and get the second line from the circle to the oval, there is an error because that line exists. Basically I want to make two vertices within the oval, as the original diagram does. (Ideally I would like to rotate the oval as well if anyone has any ideas - note that the attempt at rotating the oval I have tried has no effect on it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this level of complexity I would recommend switching directly to the underlying drawing engine (which is [Metapost](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107489/what-is-metapost-metafont-and-how-can-i-get-started-using-it)).  You can still access all the `feynmp` macros by doing `input feynmp` at the top, then you can just draw directly.  For example:

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

input feynmp

beginfig(1);

draw photon  origin -- 30 right;
draw photon  origin -- 36 right rotated 45;
draw photon (origin -- 36 right rotated 45) shifted (-3,3); 

path p; p = origin -- 72 left;

draw subpath(0,1/2) of p rotated  30; 
draw subpath(0,1/2) of p rotated -30;

arrow_len := 7;
draw fermion subpath(1,1/2) of p rotated 30;
draw fermion subpath(1/2,1) of p rotated -30;

for t = -15 step 10 until 15:
  drawarrow ((photon subpath (.5,.83) of p) .. subpath (.88,.95) of p) rotated t;
endfor

fill fullcircle scaled 20 withcolor .7 white;
draw fullcircle scaled 20;

fill fullcircle xscaled 20 yscaled 50 shifted 30 left withcolor .7 white;
draw fullcircle xscaled 20 yscaled 50 shifted 30 left;

label.lrt(btex $p$ etex,  point .8 of p rotated +30);
label.urt(btex $p'$ etex, point .8 of p rotated -30);
label.lft(btex $\vcenter{\halign{\hfil$#$\hfil\cr k_1\cr\vdots\cr k_n\cr}}$ etex, point 1 of p);
label.bot(btex $\displaystyle\underbrace{\kern40bp}_{\hbox{hard}}$ etex, (12,-9));
label.bot(btex $\displaystyle\underbrace{\kern44bp}_{\hbox{soft}}$ etex, (-44,-36));

endfig;
end
```

which produces this attempt at your diagram:

[image]

Comment: Wow brilliant, that's exactly what I wanted! So I've saved that as a metapost file, how do I then put into Latex? Putting it straight in as 
    
    \includegraphics{filename}

doesn't work

Comment: The integration into the PDF file works perfectly here, either with LaTeX+dvips, PDFLaTeX, XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. Did you load the `graphicx` package? In recent TeX distributions it should call the `epstopdf` utility to convert the EPS file into a PDF one automatically — in case PDFLaTeX or LuaLaTeX are in use — before being integrated. Otherwise the `eps` file should be integrated straight away.

Comment: I have included both the graphicx and the epstopdf package. Should I be using Latex->PDF or Latex->DVI->PDF? (It doesn't work with either of them currently) I have tried saving the file as an eps and as an mp file, but these just leave a blank space for the diagram, whereas if I save it as an mps file I get an error "cannot determine size of graphic in diagram.mps (No bounding box"

Comment: Both `LaTex-->PDF` (which means PDFLaTeX I suppose) and `LaTeX->DVI->PDF` (LaTeX + dvips + pstopdf ?) should work… Note that in recent TeX distributions it should not be necessary to include the `epstopdf` package. What are your TeX Distribution and editor? What if you replace the line `outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";` by `outputtemplate := "%j%c.mps";` and then use PDFLaTeX? Another option would be to delete/comment the `outputtemplate` line and call the `mptopdf`utility, to get a PDF figure: in the command line, `mptopdf diagram.mp`.

Comment: I am using the MikTex and Texniccentre. If I replace the eps with mps then I again get the "cannot determine size of graphic in diagram.mps (No bounding box)" error message

Comment: @supercoolphysicist Even if you use PDFLaTeX (LaTeX -> PDF) to include the `mps` file? NB: it should work directly, with `graphicx`(and without `epstopdf`).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20844/discussion-between-supercoolphysicist-and-fpast).